# How do I display folders in date of creation order?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and developing a project called BaboonHut.com, I am coding it in PHP as the best way to learn is by just diving in. Anyway to the question, the snippet of code below currently gets the name of all the folders in a certain location and displays some information, however the items are currently displaying in alphabetical order and I would like them to display in order of folder creation. SimpleHost should be in front of Code-Game-Sleep http://www.baboonhut.com/resources/, Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$dir = 'resources/';

foreach(glob($dir.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $resdir) {
    $resdir = str_replace($dir, '', $resdir);
    echo "
<div class=\"span3\">
<div class=\"tile\">
<img src=\"resources/". $resdir ."/thumbnail.png\" class=\"img-rounded\">
<h3 class=\"tile-title\">". $resdir ."</h3>
<p>"; echo  include('resources/'. $resdir .'/description.txt'); echo "</p>
<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block\" href=\"http://www.baboonhut.com/resources/" . $resdir ."/\">More Information</a>
</div>
</div>
"
;
}
?>
```

Comment: Include the code in the post, please

Comment: Sorry about that, I included it in pastebin as I thought it would be less messy :P

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php

Answer (score 2):

This will grab a list of files from a directory put them into an array then sort the array by date.

```
<?php
$dir = 'resources/';
$files = [];

foreach(glob($dir.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $resdir) {
    $files[] = [
        "name" => $resdir,
        "time" => filectime($resdir)
    ];
}

// Sort files by date
usort($files, function($a, $b){
    return $b["time"] - $a["time"];
});

foreach($files as $resdir) {
    $resdir = str_replace($dir, '', $resdir);
    echo <<<HTML
    <div class="span3">
    <div class="tile">
    <img src="resources/$resdir/thumbnail.png" class="img-rounded">
    <h3 class="tile-title">$resdir</h3>
    <p>
HTML;
    readfile('resources/'. $resdir .'/description.txt'); 
    echo <<<HTML
    </p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" href="http://www.baboonhut.com/resources/$resdir/">More Information</a>
    </div>
    </div>
HTML;
}
```

Comment: How would I change this to grab directories instead of files?

Comment: This does get directories instead of files.

Comment: How would I merge this code with the snippet I included? as in, what would I keep and what would I replace?

Comment: Use HEREDOC it is a bit more readable with that much HTML in a string. You may be getting a 500 because a file doesn't exist. check your log files.

Comment: Ah yes, the log says "File does not exist: /var/www/resources/js, referer: http://www.baboonhut.com/resources/" Why is it trying to get to a JS folder

Comment: Ah, Nope, I added that in and still nothing :/

Comment: do a `var_dump($resdir)` maybe it isn't pointing to the correct spot

Comment: Nope its pointing the the right place alright, do you have skype, might be better to talk on their than spamming up the comments.
Skype: wpcheese

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31009/discussion-between-ryan-naddy-and-thegiantbaboon)

Answer (score 1):

You can't beat [**`DirectoryIterator`**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.directoryiterator.php).

```
$files = array();
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('.');
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
   // Add only directories into a associative array, that key is it `MTime`
   if($fileinfo->isDir()){
       $files[$fileinfo->getMTime()] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
   }
}

// Then, key sort it.
ksort($files);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Creation Date

```
$files = glob(__DIR__ . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

// Using Creation Date
usort($files, function ($a, $b) {
    return filetime($a) - filetime($b);
});

foreach($files as $file) {
    printf("%s : %s\n", date("r", fileatime($file)), $file);
}

function filetime($file) {
    return PHP_OS == "win" ? fileatime($file) : filectime($file);
}
```

Using Modification Date

```
$files = glob(__DIR__ . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

// Using Modification Date
usort($files, function ($a, $b) {
    return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);
});

foreach($files as $file) {
    printf("%s : %s\n", date("r", fileatime($file)), $file);
}
```

**Note :** Using `$a - $b` in descending other but if you want descending please use `$b - $a`