# Sorting by upload/modified date PHP code

Tags: php

I'm trying to get my PHP code to sort my files by upload/modified date but having issues. Does someone know how to do this or push me in the right direction?

Here is my working code so far:

```
$dir = 'files';
$file_display = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

if(file_exists($dir) == false){
echo 'Directory \''.$dir,'\' not found!';
} else {
$dir_contents = scandir($dir);
foreach($dir_contents as $file){
    $file_type = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));

    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && in_array($file_type, $file_display) == true){
        echo '<img src="', $dir, '/', $file,'" alt="', $file, '" width="700" height="700" />';
        echo "<br />\n<br />\n";

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the filenames by via PHP's `usort()` function as follows:

```php
usort($dir_contents, create_function('$a,$b', 'return filemtime("'.$dir.'/$a")<filemtime("'.$dir.'/$b");'));
```

The above sorts array by file's last modification time. For sorting by the file's creation time you can replace `filemtime` with `filectime` function (also you can check [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php#refsect1-function.filectime-notes) for a return values meaning in Unix), or remember/retrieve file upload time from database. The above compact php sorting is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php#2667105).

Another way is to sort images in Javascript. Your PHP code then can look like this:

```php
<div id="container">
<?php
$dir = 'files';
$file_display = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
if(file_exists($dir) == false){
    echo 'Directory \''.$dir,'\' not found!';
} else {
    $dir_contents = scandir($dir);
    foreach($dir_contents as $file){
        if($file == '.' || $file == '..') { continue; }
        $arr = explode('.',$file);
        $file_type = strtolower(end($arr));
        if(in_array($file_type, $file_display)){
            echo '<img src="', $dir, '/', $file,'" alt="', $file,
                '" data-m="', filemtime("$dir/$file"),
                '" data-u="', filectime("$dir/$file"), '" />';
        }
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

and related javascript

```js
var container, images, arr;

function prepare_images(){
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    images = container.getElementsByTagName('img');//nodeList object
    arr = [];
    for (var i=0;i<images.length;i++) {
        arr[i] = images[i];
    }
    sort_images('data-m');
}

function sort_images(attr){
    arr.sort(function(a,b){
        return parseInt(a.getAttribute(attr),10) - parseInt(b.getAttribute(attr),10);
    });
    for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
      container.appendChild(arr[i]);
    }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", prepare_images, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", prepare_images); //for IE5-8
}
```

[test.php @ pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mzewX5L6)

Comment: Stano, i keep trying the use the javascript code but it keeps giving me a white screen

Comment: Ops it was my fault, forgot to test it in older Explorers. Now it works good in all browsers. Also added images sorting by filename, see here: http://pastebin.com/mzewX5L6