# news ordering by file name from files in directory

Tags: php, readdir

I need my script to sort the .txt files by date.
it's like a simple news script, what i do is adding .txt files named:

[23.7.13] New cool title
[24.7.13] advices and tips

and echo the contents,
already have everything ready including the echo part
but it wont sort them by the first dates.. how can i do this?

```
<?
    if( $handle = opendir( 'includes/news' )) 
    {
        while( $file = readdir( $handle )) 
        {
            if( strstr( $file, "txt" ) )
            {
                $addr = strtr($file, array('.txt' => ''));
                echo '<h1><a href="?module=news&read=' . $addr . '">&raquo;' .
                    $addr . "</a></h1>";
            }
         }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php

Comment: this one orders by date modified, if i reupload all the files or move a server it will be messy once again, no?

Comment: Read them all to an array. Apply array sort. Only then loop and echo.

Comment: can anyone show me on code how to do this please

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = array();
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('includes/news');
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {     
    $files[$fileinfo->getMTime()] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
}

ksort($files);
```

EDIT: (try this);

```
<?
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('includes/news');
//$dir = new DirectoryIterator('.');
$num = 0;
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {     
$name = $fileinfo->getFilename();
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/',$string, $matches); 
//preg_match_all('/\-(.*?)\-/',$name, $matches);
if(!empty($matches[1])) {
    //create timestamp (to use for key)
    $timestamp = strtotime($matches[1][0]);
    //use this as array key (to order by with ksort()
    $files[$timestamp]['name'] = $name;
}
}

//sort 
ksort($files);

//get the key back to the normal date 
foreach($files as $key=>$value) {
    $sorted_files[date('d.m.Y',$key)] = $value; 
}

var_dump($files);
?>
```

Comment: sorry, but getMtime will not do the trick,
i'm going to update the .txt files every once in a while, i need it to sort them by the first [date] prefix in the file name and generate the title by the file name.

Comment: wow, some work right there. :D but - Fatal error: Call to undefined function msort()

Comment: did you include the msort() function I posted above?