# webcam send snapshot to my website automatically how can i display them?

Tags: php, html, database, webcam

Hello I have a webcam 'foscom' that send automatic snapshot every 30minutes a pictures to this folder in my ftp "testcamera/img"

I was able to create a code that display the latest image uploaded in php.

But i want also to display a drop down menu that display all old image that's mean i will let the viewer to choose another picture and display it.
An example of the idea i want: http://www.skileb.com/webcam/mzaarv/
My Sample look like this: www.stevendahdah.com/testcamera/index.php

So anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you upload the code you are using to display the latest uploaded image?

Comment: did you try and look how to get a dropdown in html (`<select>`), how to get your list of files in php and how to do a foreach? This sounds a bit like "write my code for me" because this at least should have made you come up with some sort of try? Why not try it, see how far you come, and then as a specific question?

Comment: Dear @Nanne i created a dropdown menu and i displayed all the image in this menu but i didn't know hot to select the image but not i will try it.

Comment: And for @AnudeepBulla i am ussing this code:

<?php

$pictures = glob("img/*.jpg"); 

$no_pictures = count($pictures)-1;  // was missing ;

$limit = $no_pictures-0;            // was missing ;

for( $i = $no_pictures; $i >= $limit; $i--){  // removed ; after $i--

echo "<img src=\"".$pictures[$i]."\" />\n"; 

}  
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link that will get you started :

[sort files by date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php)

Getting the first or last file is merely getting the correct element from your sorted array :

```
$latest_file = $files[1];
$oldest_file = $files[count($files)];
```

You can create a image  tag

```
echo '<img src="/dir/where/files/are/'.$latest_file . '" />';
```

For the rest, you can create links

```
for ($i  = 2;  $i <= count($files); $i++) {
   echo '<a href="/dir/where/files/are/'.$latest_file . '" />' . $latest_file . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try it, there is a code to rename the image file automatically by date and time when uploaded to ftp from the webcam?
snapshot examples names:00626E45AAFB(e1)_0_20131127153812_12 
00626E45AAFB(e1)_0_20131127153842_13
i want 00626E45AAFB(e1)_0_20131127153812_12 i want to be: 03:38:12-27112013 or something like this. Thanks