# Find most recent JSON file in a server directory

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I can't really match an answer to this issue so I've decided to post this question hoping to find a solution.

I would like to use preferably JQuery / javascript or even PHP to find the most recent JSON files in a specified directory.

**Why I would like to do this?** Because when a user of my html5/javascript webapplication saves some array of objects to a JSON file, then besides the original work JSON file, there is a backup file that is created with a random name and which is the exact copy of the original JSON file.

If something happens to the original JSON file **I would like the user to be able to open the most recent backup files from the backups directoy and select the right one to be recovered**.

To open a JSON file I usually use this code:

```
$.getJSON('main/backups/random1345004.json', function(info){ ... });
```

Now the trouble is that in case of a backup I don't know the name of the JSON file that should be opened, because each file is unic and has a Math.random() generated name when it's created.

So I repeat the question: **Is there a way to open from the backups directory the most recently created, randomly named, JSON files?**

If not I might try to use ***.getTime()*** javascript method instead of ***Math.random()*** to control the names of the backup files created and then use a loop to search for a valid backup file name. That's a hunch, but I would not like to make anything stupid if there is a better solution, without loops.

*Security is not a concern for me at this rate.*

Thank you for any help provided!

Comment: This is going to become less and less performant as your application grows. Seems like you should really consider putting this in a database.

Comment: I consider it already! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server supports WebDav or FTP on your `main\backups` folder then you could search for all files greater today and then select the more recent.

--- Addition ---

With PHP, take a look at [sort files by date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php)

Comment: Yes. I use FTP to connect to my server but I don't understand how can a user search for the files through my web application? I wont't give them full FTP access.

Comment: You could create an `anonymous` that only allows directory read access to the specific folder.  The FTP scheme allows username and password, `ftp://anonynous:nothing@host/...`

Comment: No. It has to be done through the webapplication with javascript/ JQuery or PHP to have  a nice flow in the page even if the JSON has to be recovered.

Comment: Well your question asked `is there any way` and `security is not a concern`.

Comment: Under `security is not a concercn` I've meant the use of client side solutions such as JQuery get(). And is there any way within JQuery, javascript, PHP, html5 frames. You're right, sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: There's a javascript library for WebDAV http://ajaxian.com/archives/javascript-webdav-client

Comment: Your --- Addition --- solved my problem. It's exactly what I needed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2667105/1863061 . Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could replace your `$.getJSON()` call with a standard ajax request:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url      : "getMostRecentBackup.php",
    datatype : "json"
})
.done(function(data){
    console.log( data.toSource() );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
});
</script>
```

**getMostRecentBackup.php** will read backup directory and return a JSON object containing the most recent backup file, please read this Topic: [sort files by date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php)