# Sort file by last modified date, get the file name( not absolute path)

Tags: php

I want to get all the file name from a directory, and sort by last modified date.
I googled and get lots of answers, so I picked one from [sort files by date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php)

```
<?php
$files = array();
$dir = getcwd();
$dir = dirname($dir);  //get Parent directory
$dir .= "/XMLdata/*.xml";

$files = glob($dir);
usort($files, function($a, $b) {
    return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
});
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($files);
?>
```

From the code above, I can get the all the xml file from the directory XMLdata, However, from the result $files. I get all the files, but with absolute Path, which is "c:\wamp\www/XMLdata/xxxx.xml", and I just want the file xxxx.xml. 
I could process it in javascript use regular expression, But I think there must be a better way to get just the file name. Can anyone help me, thanks.

If there is no good way, I can use

```
           str = result[numberIndex];//one of absolute path from php
           var array = str.split("/");
           str = array[array.length - 1];
```

I can get the right filename.

Idea from @born loser

```
<?php
$files = array();
$dir = getcwd();
$dir = dirname($dir);  //get Parent directory
$dir .= "/XMLdata/*.xml";

$files = glob($dir);
usort($files, function($a, $b) {
    return filemtime($b) < filemtime($a);
});
foreach($files as &$value)
{
     $value = substr($value,strrpos($value,'/')+1);
}
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($files);
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php

Comment: yes, I get answer from there as I said

Comment: I can use function like this: array = path.split("/");
 array[array.length - 1]; to get the file name, but I think it is not a good way

Comment: Sorry - yes the array $files would have the filenames in the directory ./

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why bother..
This is what i do:

```
$i = strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'/');
define('URLBASE',   substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],0,$i+1));
```

If you can be sure to find a '/':

```
$sFile = substr($sPath,strrpos($sPath,'/')+1);
```

Comment: thanks, but I do not know how to add your lines of code.  I can get the right file name, after processing each absolute path.

Comment: thanks, I use foreach($files as &$value)
{
     $value = substr($value,strrpos($value,'/')+1);
}.

Comment: Great :-) i didn't yet know the trick with the reference inside the foreach statement. thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - yes the array $files would have the filenames in the directory ./

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($files); $i++) {
    echo $files[$i];
}
```

would return all the filenames - you would just need to play around with the filemtime function in sorting them

(this is in reference to the first answer in the question you linked to)

Comment: thanks, actually, I tried the first,but not get the result. and I think after ksort, we can get the array which is sort by date  <?php
$files = array();
$dir = getcwd();
$dir = dirname($dir); 
$dir .= "/XMLdata";
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
       if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
          $files[filemtime($file)] = $file;
       }
   }
   closedir($handle);

ksort($files);
}
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($files);
?>