# How to echo all the files in a directory based the date it was last modified php

Tags: php, file, directory, echo

I am using the code below to echo out all the files from a directory onto a page. The order of the files that are echoed out are in a random order, i.e,

File 3

File 1

File 2

Instead of

File 1

File 2

File 3

How do I make it so that the files that are echoed out are based on when it was created or uploaded. The most recent files will appear at the top of the list, and the oldest file will appear at the bottom

```
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && !in_array($entry, $blacklist)) {
            echo "<p>$entry\n</p>";
        } 



    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here i get all files from a directory with [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), then i sort it with a user defined function [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and compare the times of the last modification with [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php))

```
<?php

    function cmp($a, $b) {
        if (filemtime($a) == filemtime($b))
            return 0;

        return (filemtime($a) < filemtime($b)) ? -1 : 1;
    }


    $files = glob("*.*");
    usort($files, "cmp");

    foreach($files as $file)
        echo $file . "<br />";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PHP4+'s **filemtime**. You're going to want to do 2 things here:

1. Get the file's filemtimes, in an array
2. Sort them based on the filemtime comparison

Answer (score 0):

Next time try to search on stackoverflow for questions similar to yours :)

```
    $files = array();
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
       if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
          $files[filemtime($file)] = $file;
       }
   }
   closedir($handle);



// sort ksort($files); // find the last modification $reallyLastModified = end($files);


foreach($files as $file) { $lastModified = date('F d Y, H:i:s',filemtime($file)); if(strlen($file)-strpos($file,".swf")== 4){ if ($file == $reallyLastModified) { // do stuff for the real last modified file } echo "$file$lastModified"; } }
```

Not tested

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php)