# How to sort by date using PHP opendir()

Tags: php, directory, echo, opendir

I have  a directory full of files that I am trying to echo out. If  the file is an image, the image itself is echoed out. If the file is not an image, the name of the file is echoed out.

This code below works perfectly however I can't seem to get the order sorted by date. The files are randomly echoed out.

How would I make it so that the files are sorted by last modified (latest first).

```
<?php


$blacklist = array("index.php");
$ext = pathinfo($files, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ($handle = opendir('.')) {

    $valid_image = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) { 
       krsort($entry);

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && !in_array($entry, $blacklist)) {

            $exploded = explode('.', $entry);

            if(in_array(end($exploded), $valid_image))
            {
              echo "<div><h4>"; echo date('d F Y', filemtime($file)) . "</h4><a href='" . $entry . "'><img src='".$entry."'></a></div><hr>";
            }
            else
            {
              echo "<div><h4>"; echo date('d F Y', filemtime($file)) . "</h4><a href='" . $entry . "'>" . $entry . "</a></div>";
            }
        } 
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure how that would be done in this context

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create an empty array, outside your loop
$files = array();

while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) { 
    if(in_array(end($exploded), $valid_image)){

       // Instead of echoing the string, add it to the array, using filemtime as the array key
       $files[filemtime($file)] = "<div><h4>".date('d F Y', filemtime($file)) . "</h4><a href='$entry'><img src='$entry'></a></div><hr>";

    } else...
}

// reverse sort on the array
krsort($files);        

// output the array in a loop
foreach($files as $file){
    echo $file;
}
```