# how to show images by date in fancy box

Tags: php, image, date, upload, fancybox

i've made a fancy box showing images uploaded in back-end by my client, but the gallery is showing images by their names, how can i make it showing by date of upload?

this is the fancy-box gallery code:

```html
<?php
  $villa = "img/travaux/villa/";
  $dir = opendir($villa);
  while($file = readdir($dir)){
   $allow_ext = array("jpg",'png','gif');
   $ext = strtolower(substr($file,-3));
   if(in_array($ext,$allow_ext)){
?>
  <a href="img/travaux/villa/<?php echo $file; ?>" class="fancybox-thumb" data-fancybox-group="villa">
<?php
   }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use:- exif_read_data?? This exif read the header of the images

Comment: @Garima the question is “how can i make it showing by **date of upload**” EXIF is insignificant for this

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/2667065/1055987 if that helps

Comment: There is not an easier way to make an option In my fancybox script for fix it ?

Comment: Nope (not easier) ... and if I have the chance to do it server side I would rather do it that way