# How do I sort opendir by date PHP?

Tags: php, list, sorting, opendir

I have this simple code that displays a list of files from a directory

```
<?php
$dir = opendir("pages");
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
{
if($file !="." AND $file !=".."){
echo "<a href=\"show_page.php?file=" .$file . "\">".$file."</a>";
echo "<br />";
}
}
closedir($dir);
?>
```

Can anyone please help edit this code to order the list displayed by date modified?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/sort-files-by-date-in-php

Comment: I already checked it but the solutions listed didnt work for me, I have been trying them for hours.

Comment: Since you're opening a different directory than `.`, you need to prepend the directory name to the filename when you call `filemtime()`: `filemtime("$pages/$file")`.

Comment: If you still can't get it to work, you need to show your code. Just saying "it didn't work for me" is not useful.

Comment: I am not a PHP programmer, so starting from zero is probably much better than trying to edit my existing code (which is a mess), thats why I started a new question, to save a headache..