# Unable to Rename the latest file in a folder with PHP

Tags: php, sorting, rename, file-rename

I want to rename the latest added file from a folder, but somehow my code isn't working. Could please help!

For example, if the latest file is "file_0202.json"
And I want to Change it to "file.json"

**Here is my Code**

```
<?php

$files = scandir('content/myfiles', SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$selected_file = $files[0];

$new_filename = preg_replace('/_[^_.]*\./', '.', $selected_file);

if(rename($selected_file, $new_filename, ))
{
echo 'renamed';
}
else {
echo 'can not rename';
}

?>
```

Comment: `SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING` is _alphabetical_ sorting, what does that have to do with "latest"?

Comment: You are trying to rename the source file in the current script execution folder. But that is not where it is located, it is located in `content/myfiles`. You need to prepend the path to both the old and new file name.

Comment: @CBroe oh yeah, you are right. is there a function to point the latest file ?

Comment: No, the functions for reading from a directory don't generally provide that option, you'll have to sort them yourself, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667065/how-to-sort-files-by-date-in-php

Comment: @CBroe Thanks a lot for the reference.  So from there, if i happen to set the latest file name to "$selected_file",          but still this won't work, yeah ?      rename($selected_file, $new_filename).   Its bugging me so much

Comment: As I said, you need to prepend the proper path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better if you use [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). glob() returns the path and filename used.

Then you have to sort by the file that was last changed. You can use [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and [filemtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime) for that.

```
$files = glob('content/myfiles/*.*');

usort($files,function($a,$b){return filemtime($b) <=> filemtime($a);});

$selected_file = $files[0];
$new_filename = preg_replace('/_[^_.]*\./', '.', $selected_file);
if(rename($selected_file, $new_filename))
{
  echo 'renamed';
}
else {
  echo 'can not rename';
}
```

Instead of *.* you can restrict the searched files if necessary. As an example *.json . Be careful with your regular expression so that it doesn't change a path.